# how to compare a user entered date to the current date and change a fields background color?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am working on a fallible PDF form and trying to set it to do multiple things. The first is I need to compare a user entered date to the current date to see if it is withing 5 years to the day. The second thing I need it to do is to change a fields background color if that date is at the 5 year time or outside of that range. This is the code I have been trying but it hasn't worked so far. There are 37 fields that need to be checked by this.

```
for(i=1;i<38;i++){

var Y = d.getFullYear(); 
var d = new Date();
var M = d.getMonth(); 

var d = new Date();
var D = d.getDay(); //n =2

var strDate = this.getField("Text"+[i]).value;
var arrDate = strDate.split('/');

var month = arrDate[0];
var day = arrDate[1];
var year = arrDate[2];

if(year+5>=Y){
if(M<=month){
if(D<=day){
this.getField("Text[i]").fillColor=color.red;
}}}}
```

Comment: Why the nested ``if`` statements? Use ``&&`` to clean that area up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated this, it working now, can you try this now ?

```js
for(i=1;i<38;i++)
{
  var todayDate = new Date();
  var strDate = "12/25/2009";
  var arrDate = strDate.split('/');
  
  var month = arrDate[0];
  var day = arrDate[1];
  var year = parseInt(arrDate[2]) + 5;
  
  var userEnteredDate = new Date(year, month, day);
  
  if(userEnteredDate <= todayDate)
  {
    //Color change code here...
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var d = new Date(),
    Y = d.getFullYear(),
    M = d.getMonth() + 1, // since this returns 0 - 11
    D = d.getDay() + 1, // since this returns 0 - 30
    strDate,
    arrDate,
    month,
    day,
    year;

for(var i = 1; i < 38; i++) {
    strDate = this.getField("Text" + i).value;
    arrDate = strDate.split('/');

    month = parseInt(arrDate[0], 10);
    day = parseInt(arrDate[1], 10);
    year = parseInt(arrDate[2], 10);

    if (((Y + 5) * 12 + M < year * 12 + month) || ((Y + 5) * 12 + M === year * 12 + month && D < day)) {
        this.getField("Text" + i).fillColor = color.red;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but when I tried this code, it turns the every value in the column red except blank spaces, not just the ones that are older than 5 years

Comment: Oh, _older_ than 5 years! I switched the inequality signs, try that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach so far as I know, is to instantiate a `Date` that is five years ago based on current time:

```
var t = new Date()
t.setFullYear(t.getFullYear() - 5) // t is five years ago
```

Then you just need to substract the user input date with this one, and see if the result is positive or negative:

```
var ut = new Date("......") // the Date instance from user input
if(ut - t >= 0) {
    // within 5 years
} else {
    // more than 5 years ago
}
```

The reason you can do so, is because when you substract two `Date` instances one another, they will be internally converted to timestamps. The less a timestamp is, the earlier the time is. So the result of substraction (a number) represents the time in between, in milliseconds.

If you don't care how long in between, you could just compare them:

```
var ut = new Date("......") // the Date instance from user input
if(ut >= t) {
    // within 5 years
} else {
    // more than 5 years ago
}
```

Comment: thanks but when I tried this code, it turns the every value in the column red, not just the ones that are older than 5 years when i plugged it in and tried to loop through my column. Here is what I used:                  for(i=1;1<38;i++){

    var t = new Date()
    t.setFullYear(t.getFullYear() - 5) // t is five years ago

    var ut = new Date("Text"+i) // the Date instance from user input
    if(ut - t >= 0) {
        // within 5 years
    this.getField("Text"+i).fillColor=color.green;
    } else {
       // more than 5 years ago
    this.getField("Text"+i).fillColor=color.red;
    }
    }

Comment: @JB11 is it pseudo code, or you are actually running? `new Date("Text"+i)` would possibly give you an **invalid date**, so that `ut - t` will be `NaN`, definitely fails the comparison. You may take a look at the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on how to insantiate a valid date with `Date` constructor. One more thing, get the `t` out of the loop, you don't have to do it in every iteration.